# Rewriting SQL query to get record id and customer number

Tags: sql, oracle

**Sample data**

```
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| RECORD_ID         | CUST_NO     | IsAccntClosed   | Code                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|159045             |   2439123   | N               |   13                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|159048             |   6376150   | Y               |   13                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|159048             |   9513035   | N               |   13                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|159049             |   2398524   | N               |   12                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|159049             |   6349269   | Y               |   12                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|159049             |   6350690   | Y               |   12                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|159049             |   6372163   | Y               |   12                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|159049             |   6393810   | Y               |   12                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|159049             |   6402062   | Y               |   12                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|159050             |   2677512   | Y               |   12                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|159050             |   6349382   | Y               |   12                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|159050             |   6378137   | Y               |   12                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|159051             |   2336197   | N               |   12                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|159051             |   6349293   | N               |   12                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|159051             |   6350682   | N               |   12                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|159051             |   6367895   | N               |   12                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|159060             |   yyyyyy    | Y               |   12                |
+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

IsAccntClosed column indicates if the account is Open (Y) or account is closed (Y).

I need to select Record_ID and cust_no for only those rows for which which Record_Id satisfies one of the below condition :
1. Only one cust account is open , there might be one or multiple closed customers
2. No open customer and only one closed customer

Expected output :
159045 2439123
159048 9513035
159049 2398524
159060 yyyyyy

A query like this would take each row as a single group and the count will come as 1

```
select RECORD_ID, CUST_NO, IsAccntClosed, count(IsAccntClosed), Code
  from table1
 group by RECORD_ID, CUST_NO, IsAccntClosed, Code
```

Any suggestions on how this query could be written to get the expected output?

Comment: What datatype is "IsAccntClosed"?

Comment: updated the question. IsAccntClosed is Character data type. IsAccntClosed indicates if the customer account is Open or closed

Comment: I suspect everyone here (in [oracle]) requires help with a query

Comment: @Strawberry Is it not valid to ask for help in a query?

Comment: It's just not a very imaginative title

Comment: Doesn't condition 1 conflict with 2? "Only one cust account is open" vs. "No open customer"

Comment: Do you mean satisfies one of those 2 conditions? (not both) I don't see how both conditions can be satisfied

Comment: @BrianDeMilia I'll update the question, Its should satisfy one of those 2 conditions

Comment: @charanraj in your expected output you show only one cust_no value for each record_id. Those record_id values have multiple associated cust_no values. How do you determine which cust_no value to show for each of the record_id values meeting the criteria?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia This query is actually a part of process where in a customer number which satisfies the condition is being assigned to the record id. One record id can show multiple customer numbers but this needs to be filtered down and I need to arrive at one customer number per record Id for the given condition

Comment: @charanraj you've only given us conditions that record_id must satisfy, not conditions which customer_id must satisfy

Comment: @charanraj if it simply lines up with your record_id condition, what would you want to do w/ record_id values having BOTH just one closed customer and just one open customer? Which takes priority?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia in this case the Customer number which is open would be taken for the given record id the closed account should be ignored

Comment: @charanraj okay, I just updated my answer to work that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being IsAccntClosed a CHAR column, you should be able to get what you want with a query like this:

```
SELECT a.record_id,
  (CASE
     WHEN a.CountOpen=1 THEN a.CustNoOpen
     ELSE                    a.CustNoClosed
  END) AS cust_no
FROM (
  SELECT b.record_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN b.IsAccntClosed='N' THEN b.cust_no ELSE NULL END) AS CustNoOpen  ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.IsAccntClosed='N' THEN 1         ELSE 0    END) AS CountOpen   ,
    MAX(CASE WHEN b.IsAccntClosed='Y' THEN b.cust_no ELSE NULL END) AS CustNoClosed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.IsAccntClosed='Y' THEN 1         ELSE 0    END) AS CountClosed
  FROM table1 b
  GROUP BY b.record_id
) a
WHERE a.CountOpen=1 OR (a.CountOpen=0 AND a.CountClosed=1)
```

The inner query is grouping the table. It counts the open and closed accounts and takes one (random) cust_no of any of the closed accounts and one (random) of any of the open accounts, per group.

The outer query filters the data and cleans everything up, placing the open or closed cust_no in the output result column.

Notice that the WHERE condition of the outer query has the collateral effect that, since you are looking for records that have just a single open or a single closed account, those random cust_no which have been selected by the inner query, are now significant.

**EDIT**: I fixed the query and tested it on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f18f6/9).

Answer (score 1):

In the below I added another record:

```
insert into tbl values (159060, 'zzzzzz', 'N', 12);
```

to illustrate what would happen if a record_id has just one open cust_no and just one closed cust_no. Note how in the result the cust_no returned is the zzzzz one, because that account is open, which you mentioned wanting to take precendence over closed, in the event of a tie 1:1 (zzzzzz should take over yyyyyy in this case, because yyyyyy is closed whereas zzzzzz is open)

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5cb60/1/0

```
with one_open as
 (select record_id
    from tbl
   where IsAccntClosed = 'N'
   group by record_id
  having count(distinct cust_no) = 1),
one_closed as
 (select record_id
    from tbl
   where IsAccntClosed = 'Y'
   group by record_id
  having count(distinct cust_no) = 1),
bothy as
 (select record_id from one_open intersect select record_id from one_closed)
select *
  from tbl
 where (record_id in (select record_id from one_open) and
       IsAccntClosed = 'N')
    or (record_id not in (select record_id from one_open) and
       record_id in (select record_id from one_closed) and
       IsAccntClosed = 'Y' and
       record_id not in (select record_id from bothy))
```

Comment: Thanks for giving your time to provide a solution. Your quer y is working but I'll have to select Frazz's answer in my case since the table shown above is being derived using queries and putting them inside your query makes it a little hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  record_id,
  cust_no
from (
  select
    record_id,
    cust_no,
    count(case when isAccntClosed='Y' then 1 else null end)
      over (partition by record_id) closed_accounts,
    count(case when isAccntClosed='N' then 1 else null end)
      over (partition by record_id) open_accounts
  from
    table1
  )
where (open_accounts = 1)
   or (open_accounts = 0 and closed_accounts = 1)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. He wants the cust_no of that single open or closed account. And how will those COUNT work without a GROUP BY?

Comment: @Frazz with the `over` clause, the count becomes an analytic function, as opposed to a standard aggregate function. So for each row it includes the count across the given partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select RECORD_ID,
       (case when sum(case when IsAccntClosed = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
             then max(case when IsAccntClosed = 'N' then max(CUST_NO) end)
             else max(CUST_NO)
        end) as cust_no
from table1
group by RECORD_ID
having sum(case when IsAccntClosed = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 or
       (sum(case when IsAccntClosed = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
        sum(case when IsAccntClosed = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
       )
```

It is probably easier to understand the logic using subqueries:

```
select recordId,
       (case when numOpen > 0 then OpenCustNo else closedCustNo end) as CustNo
from (select t1.RecordId, sum(case when IsAccntClosed = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) as numOpen,
             sum(case when IsAccntOpen = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) as numClosed,
             max(case when IsAccntClosed = 'N' then cust_no end) as OpenCustNo,
             max(case when IsAccntClosed = 'Y' then cust_no end) as ClosedCustNo
      from table1 t1
      group by record_id
     ) r
where numOpen = 1 or numOpen = 0 and numClosed = 1;
```